# Rerendering one of the mapped elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket

My app displays posts fetched from node.js server which gets data from mysql. They are mapped in component called Posts and to each of them I pass needed data. When there is change to post (for example new like) node.js informs client to fetch data trough websocket. Client then fetches updated array of posts. The thing is that when one post is updated all off them are rerendered, since new array is passed. How can I alter my code so only the changed post will rerender? Any suggestions?

**useGetPosts**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import io from "socket.io-client";

const socket = io("http://localhost:3001");

const useGetPosts = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState<IPost[]>([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);

  const getPosts = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await axios("http://localhost:3001/activities/posts");
      setPosts(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      setError(true);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getPosts();
    socket.on("changedPosts", () => {
      getPosts();
    });
    return () => {
      socket.off("changedPosts");
    };
  }, []);

  return { posts, loading, error };
};
```

**Posts component**

```
export default function Posts() {
  const [postsAmmount, setPostsAmmount] = useState(5);
  const { posts, loading, error } = useGetPosts();
  const postsToShow = posts.slice(0, postsAmmount);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setPostsAmmount((prev) => prev + 5);
  };

  return (
    <PostsWrapper>
      {error && "Unexpected error occurred - couldn't download posts."}
      {loading ? (
        <Spinner pxSize={80} />
      ) : (
        postsToShow.map((item) => {
          return <Post post={item} key={item.postId} />;
        })
      )}
      {postsAmmount < posts.length ? (
        <div onClick={handleClick}>Show more</div>
      ) : (
        "No more posts"
      )}
    </PostsWrapper>
  );
}
```

**Post Component**

```
export default function Post({ post }: PostProps) {
  const { comments, commentsLoading, commentsError } = useGetComments(
    post.postId
  );
  const { likePost, loading, error } = usePostActions();
  const [areCommentsActive, setAreCommentsActive] = useState(false);
  const { isDarkMode } = useContext(DarkModeContext);

  const toggleComments = () => {
    setAreCommentsActive((prev) => !prev);
  };

  return (
    <PostWrapper isDarkMode={isDarkMode}>
      {commentsLoading ? (
        <Spinner pxSize={40} />
      ) : (
        <>
          <CreatorWrapper>
            <ProfileIcon image={toBase64(post.profileImage.data)} />
            <p>
              {post.firstName} {post.lastName}
            </p>
          </CreatorWrapper>
          <PostBodyWrapper>{post.postText}</PostBodyWrapper>
          <ReactionsAndComments>
            <LikesWrapper>
              {post.likes > 0 && (
                <>
                  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faThumbsUp} /> {post.likes}
                  {loading && <Spinner pxSize={30} />}
                </>
              )}
            </LikesWrapper>
            <CommentsCounterWrapper onClick={toggleComments}>
              {comments?.length! > 0
                ? `${comments?.length} Comments`
                : "No comments yet"}
              {commentsError && "Couldn't get comments"}
            </CommentsCounterWrapper>
          </ReactionsAndComments>
          <InteractionsWrapper isDarkMode={isDarkMode}>
            <div onClick={() => likePost(post.postId)}>
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faThumbsUp} /> Like
            </div>
            <div onClick={toggleComments}>
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMessage} /> Comment
            </div>
          </InteractionsWrapper>
          {areCommentsActive && (
            <CommentsSection postId={post.postId} comments={comments} />
          )}
        </>
      )}
    </PostWrapper>
  );
}
```

Comment: What problem is the rerendering of all posts posing for you? Usually in this sort of case, without more info, I'd just let them rerender.

Comment: Each of post are having its own states. Rerendering them causes that I lose values of these states.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the `<Post` component then (but it's not in the question). Rather than preventing re-rendering (which would be a little bit messy off the top of my head), better to fix the bug

Comment: How can I keep value of state through rerender then?

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing the problematic component

Comment: Updated with Post Component

Comment: The thing is that areCommentsActive is being lost for all of them and goes back to false even if it was set to true before rerender.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that while a network request is going on, none of the Posts are rendered; `loading` is true while you're waiting for the reply to come back, and if that's the case, you render `<Spinner pxSize={80} />` rather than `postsToShow.map(...)`.

State will be preserved inside a component if the component existed before the rerender, and if it also exists after the rerender. If the component doesn't exist before the rerender, state values will be re-initialized from scratch (and, for example, `useEffect(fn, [])`s will run again, and so on). During the time that `loading` is true, no Posts are being rendered, so no `<Post>` state is preserved after the response has come back and they get rendered again.

There are a few options here. I think the nicest one would be to keep rendering all Posts while loading. Instead of doing

```
<PostsWrapper>
  {error && "Unexpected error occurred - couldn't download posts."}
  {loading ? (
    <Spinner pxSize={80} />
  ) : (
    postsToShow.map((item) => {
      return <Post post={item} key={item.postId} />;
    })
  )}
  {postsAmmount < posts.length ? (
    <div onClick={handleClick}>Show more</div>
  ) : (
    "No more posts"
  )}
</PostsWrapper>
```

you could do

```
<PostsWrapper>
  {error && "Unexpected error occurred - couldn't download posts."}
  {loading && <Spinner pxSize={80} />}
  {
    postsToShow.map((item) => {
      return <Post post={item} key={item.postId} />;
    })
  )}
  {postsAmmount < posts.length ? (
    <div onClick={handleClick}>Show more</div>
  ) : (
    "No more posts"
  )}
</PostsWrapper>
```

This way, even if `loading` is true, `postsToShow.map` is still rendered. If you want the posts to be hidden while loading is going on, give the `PostsWrapper` a class that hides `Post` children *while still rendering each `Post`*. (But it may look better if you don't hide the posts - otherwise, whenever there's an update, the user may have the section they were reading completely disappear and then reappear, which isn't nice).

If you really want to completely dismount each `Post` while loading, another option would be to [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) - put the `areCommentsActive` state into the parent component as an array, and then pass down the associated value and the state setter to each child - and the same for any other state you need to preserve in the `Post`. Doable, but a bit ugly.